# How can I enable my agents to see who else is on live chat and the size of the chat queue?

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, omnichannel

Our service team leaders use Omni Supervisor extensively. However, they're wondering if there's a way to provide some of the visibility to agents - specifically, the status of other agents and the number of chats that are queuing.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Permission sets don't seem to be a viable option. We're using Lightning.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is still an Idea over IdeaExchange portal:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CMSBQA4

Request you to upvote this Idea to get it considered in future product releases.